# Is there a way to automatically check all JPG's for corrupted files?

Tags: backup

I have a lot photos and recently I tried opening an older photo and it came up black, the next photo in the folder displayed properly except the bottom 10% of the photo was garbled green blocks, and all other photos in the folder were fine. I checked my backup drive and the files were bad on it as well, luckily I had an older backup drive and the files were ok on it. So sometime between when I did the old backup and the new backup, the files went bad on my iMac.

But now I'm wondering, was this an isolated incident out my 30,000 photos, or are there more files like this? How can I find them so I'm not backing up bad files, or overwriting good files with bad files just because the file size hasn't changed. I use carbon copy cloner for backups and it has an option for detecting corrupted files, but checksum doesn't identify that these jpg's are bad, that they don't display properly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the corrupted photo also show incorrectly in non-Apple applications like Chrome or Photoshop? While unlikely it could be possible that the bug is in the JPEG code Apple's Finder, Preview and Safari are using.

Comment: Install brew and in brew jpeginfo. Then execute `jpeginfo -c ...` to check your pics. Some types of corruption won't be detected probably. Some `jpeginfo ... grep ... xargs/exec ... mv ...` magic is needed to search dirs and subdirs and move the corrupted pics.

Comment: Can you dumb this down more? :) I basically want to automatically scan all 30,000 photos on the drive and find the ones that aren't displaying properly but pass checksum.

Comment: I have posted a similar question specifically regarding Photos.app (a.k.a. iPhoto) for macOS [here](https://superuser.com/q/1546096/287154)